# Hibernate - NullPointerException on merging for a second time

Tags: java, hibernate

Having trouble merging an object, then re-merging (in a different transaction) with more updates. Getting the following stack trace:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor63.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.generateHashCode(CollectionKey.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.<init>(CollectionKey.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionKey.<init>(CollectionKey.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.postFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:391)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    ... 149 more`

I've attempted to trace the error, and think it may be something to do with a `OneToMany` list containing zero items, but after hours of searching I've found nothing on this issue.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I know what a NullPointerException is..... This question is specific to Hibernate.....

Comment: And which version of Hibernate is this specifically?

Comment: I have. All of the above stack trace is generated by Hibernate, not me. All I am doing is calling merge in Hibernate, which is a common way of updating data. Hibernate is throwing the above error.

Comment: Latest - using 4.3.6

Comment: @user2482461, check this link .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191347/nullpointerexception-on-merge it may actually be what you are looking for

Comment: @KennethClark - yes - the more I look at that issue, the more I think it's the same issue as mine. Will look into & get back to you.

Comment: OK, so after much soul searching, it turns out that because I was setting the `OneToMany` as an empty list, then merging (the returned list from this merge was still an empty list), reattempting to merge the empty list was throwing the given error. Not initialising the list at all results in me being able to merge perfectly multiple times. So, from now on, I'll initialise all lists as and when they actually have items, not when they are empty.

Comment: @user2482461 can you post what you were doing wrong as a code example in an answer, and the change to correct it? Perhaps I might learn something too (although I generally avoid using merge and work only on managed entities)